# do-while loop does not end

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, user-input, do-while

I'm attempting to do a do-while loop where the user inputs a value, either 1 or 0, and if it is not 1 or 0 then the loop will ask them to do it again until they enter 1 or 0. However, in runtime, when i enter 1 or 0, it will keep printing the stuff inside the if statement

> you have given an incorrect response, it must either be 1 or 0

even though i have entered 1/0, staying in this loop forever. Does it store the <kbd>enter</kbd> key? What am i missing and how do i fix this?

```
int validateresultmanual(char* word, char* suggestion)
{
    int choice;
    int result;

    if(suggestion == NULL)
    {
        result = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Enter 0 for yes or 1 for no: Do you want to change %s to %s?\n", word, suggestion);
            scanf("%c", &choice);
            if(choice != 0 || choice != 1)
            {
                printf("You have given an incorrect response, it must either be 1 or 0\n");
            }
            else if(choice == 0)
            {
                printf ("\n yaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n");
                result = TRUE;
            }
            else if (choice == 1)
            {
                result = FALSE;
            }
     } while (choice != 0 || choice !=1 );
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: Hint: think of a number `choice` for which both `choice != 0` and `choice != 1` would evaluate to `false`; that's the number you need to enter in order to end the loop.

Comment: Yes, it will read in the enter key.

Comment: Mega-dupe.  Many, many similar Q's:(

Answer (score 4):

Your situation check is incorrect:

change this

```
if(choice != 0 || choice != 1)
```

to

```
if(choice != 0 && choice != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the **or** with an **and**, because your *while* is checking for a condition and continuing while that condition is true.